# How do I render a view in Cakephp using FPDF

Tags: cakephp-2.3, fpdf

I’m having some difficulty getting just a basic pdf document to render within cakephp. 
(I am interested in dynamically rendering the view, not downloading the pdf.)
Here’s what I’ve done and I’m just getting a pdf gibberish.

[image: gibberish]

Added fpdf class files in the Vendor folders. 
(Vendors autoload and I have access to the class)

Created app/View/Layouts/pdf.ctp

```
 header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
    echo $content_for_layout;
```

Created controller action:

```
public function document(){
  App::import('Vendor','Fpdf/fpdf');
  $this->layout = 'pdf'; 
  $this->render()
}
```

Created matching document.ctp View for the above controller action:

```
$fpdf = new FPDF();
$fpdf->AddPage();
$fpdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
$fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello world');
$fpdf->Output();
```

In the config/routes I have tried with and without this…

```
Router::parseExtensions('pdf');
```

Where am I going wrong?
This all works so well in a non-cakephp environment.

Comment: Is document.ctp inside the View/.../pdf/document.ctp directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was pretty close. 
I've been told that the above actually works in older version of cakephp (ie 1.3). 
I didn't verify since I don't use any of the older versions.

First off... the config file modification was not needed in my case.

Deleted from the layout:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Added to the controller:

```
$this->request->type('application/pdf');
```

So simply moving the content-type declaration from the layout to the controller did the trick for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

1. On the controllar, after the namespace, put:

```
require_once ROOT . DS . 'src/Lib/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

2. Now, in the function:

   ```
    function responsiva_celulares($id) { //Name of the view
       $this->layout = '';        //Removing layout
       $this->set('id', $id); //Some variables
       $this->render()->type('application/pdf'); //Rendering the pdf
   }
   ```
3. And then, in the responsiva_celulares.ctp:

   ```
    AddPage();
    $fpdf->SetFont('Courier', 'B', 16);
    $fpdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello world ' . $id);
    $fpdf->Output();
   ```